# I need a plastic 2cm thick to made a part for a shoe cabinet

Tags: cabinets, plastic

Where can I find a plastic 2cm thick? I have a shoe/storage cabinet and I need to replace a broken part myself, from  a plastic, using a file. A completed set of replacement parts is too expensive.
[image]

Comment: Since those pieces are round, buy plastic rod stock (big box store or your favorite Grainger/McMaster/... dealer.

Comment: Or shape it from a wooden dowel, which likely would be stronger than the plastic.

Comment: Or if you have 2 identical pieces and one is still intact, use the good one to make a plaster mold, then cast a new one (or 10) in the mold from acrylic or epoxy. Take your question to https://crafts.stackexchange.com/ for help with that.

Comment: You can also likely 3d print them - I don't think there would be very extreme forces on shoe-cabinet case... There is a good chance you know someone with such printer and such folks often like to experiment with printing things. May want to check on https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/ first if that route is likely to succeed.